# NivoSlider images to capture the exact width and height of the div

Tags: nivo-slider

The slider images that I use is not the same width and height as the NivoSlider div.
I want my images to scale into the exact width and height of the NivoSlider div, with no losing any part of the image. How can i do this?

I am using the v3.2 JQuery plugin, not Wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in photoshop, but its hard if its not the same ratio, you will lose pixels

what you could do is resize the slider or edit the photo's

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am aware of this solution, but this is not what i want to do.

Comment: add a css to the image with a width and height, causes strecht thoug. Or use overflow hidden on the image. But that will only work when the image is bigger